# Django template, 'include' css rather than using link

Tags: css, django, templates

Recently we have experienced the problem of browsers caching the css files, so that when we move code to another web server we get unexpected and unwanted results.
Having read various solutions it occurred to me that the css file could be included in the template. Rather than write

```
<link href="/static/css/parentx.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

we could put

```
<style>{% include "static/css/parent.css" %}</style>
```

which would embed the css in the html. It has the added benefit of reducing the number of calls back to the server for the css file but the disadvantage of not caching the css at all and not allowing the web server to provide the static files. However, these files are quite small, typically about 12K.

I propose this as a temporary measure as I have just discovered the existence of asset management plugins that look to do a better job.
I have never seen the use of the 'include' template command to get css (and javascript) files so perhaps there is a drawback of which I am unaware?

Answer (score 0):

Not caching the CSS file at all will slow page loading though it's unnecessary.

Cache your CSS as long as possible and necessary and when you need to invalidate cache, a sure way is to load another file, I mean the same file with another name. It could be `parent1391234565.css` or `parent-v003.css` or `parent130307.css` or `parent-4e6ca1437f2d.css`. If you told browsers to download `parent-v002.css`, you're pretty certain they don't have `parent-v003.css` in their cache!

Comment: You can also employ the `?v=<some arbitrary version number>` technique which is a much better way of forcing "decaching".